# Why do i get "Error: symbol is already defined" when instantiating a C++ template with function type

Tags: c++, templates, dll, shared-libraries

I have a simple DLL library with 4 functions, 2 of which use __stdcall and 2 default __cdecl calling conventions.

In my executable i want to call all of these 4 functions and i'm using a template for it. The code is following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename FuncType>
void CallFunction( HMODULE hModule, const char * name )
{
    FuncType function = (FuncType)GetProcAddress( hModule, name );
    if (function)
        printf("result: %d.\n", function(1,2) );
    else
        printf("%s not found (%lu)\n", name, GetLastError());
}

typedef int (* FuncType1)(int, int);
typedef int (__stdcall * FuncType2)(int, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary( TEXT("library.dll") );
    if (hModule) {
        CallFunction<FuncType1>( hModule, "File1_Funkce1" );
        CallFunction<FuncType2>( hModule, "File1_Funkce2" );
        CallFunction<FuncType1>( hModule, "File2_Funkce1" );
        CallFunction<FuncType2>( hModule, "File2_Funkce2" );

        FreeLibrary( hModule );
    }
    else {
        printf("library not found\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles well with Visual Studio compiler, but throws error with MinGW:
`Error: symbol '__Z12CallFunctionIPFiiiEEvP11HINSTANCE__PKc' is already defined`. I don't see why using the templates this way would cause multiple definitions, since you can normaly instantiate `vector<int>` and `vector<char>` multiple times in the same translation unit and no errors occur.

Any idea?

**Edit:**
my compile commands were simply:

```
cl file.cpp
g++ file.cpp -o file.exe
```

Comment: Please post your compile/link commands for mingw

Comment: The demangled name it's complaining about is: _void CallFunction<int (*)(int, int)>(HINSTANCE__*, char const*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that mingw ignores `__stdcall` when mangling template names and causes name collisions. You can avoid this by encoding those pointers in their own types:

```
template<typename Func>
struct StdCall;

template<typename R, typename... Params>
struct StdCall<R(Params...)>
{
    using type = R(__stdcall *)(Params...);
};

template<typename Func>
struct Cdecl;

template<typename R, typename... Params>
struct Cdecl<R(Params...)>
{
    using type = R(*)(Params...);
};
```

And then you'd call them:

```
CallFunction<StdCall<int(int,int)>>();
CallFunction<Cdecl<int(int,int)>>();
```

You'd have to change `CallFunction` to invoke the `::type`, though:

```
template<typename FuncType>
void CallFunction( )
{
    using Func = typename FuncType::type;
}
```

Comment: oh, wow, that's a complicated workaround ... is that a bug in GCC or just disadvantage of its design?

Comment: @Youda008 well, you could make `StdCall` and `Cdecl` not templates and just encode `int(int,int)` directly as their types, but that's fairly rigid. As for whether this is a bug, I think it is, but I'm not sure if it's at mingw level or at gcc level.